# create an html file path url relative to $home

Tags: html, url, filepath

I can enter the following URL into an html file or just the part in double quotes into the Safari browser and it works.

```
<frame src="file:///Users/brian/j64-801-user/projects/tgsjhs/tgsjhshelp.html"
```

In the unix terminal I see the following.

```
server:~ brian$ Var3="$HOME"
server:~ brian$ echo "Home $Var3"
Home /Users/brian
```

But I cannot just replace `/Users/brian` with `$HOME`. Can you tell me something similar that I can use as a replacement for `/Users/brian` so that other people with the file named exactly as mine is, and whose file has the same relation to their $HOME directory, can use the path?

I would especially like an answer that would work on Mac, Windows, and Linux, if possible, although I am using a Mac.

Thanks,